# I am writing a basic chess engine in javascript. How can I insert a string at a particular element in a 3d array?

Tags: javascript, chess

I am trying to build a chess engine in javascript.  So far I have the initial set up where the pieces are placed and empty squares are marked with a '#'.  When I change the square where the piece moved from to a '#', there is no issue.  My issue comes in when I try to place the piece at its new position.  It inserts the new piece name at multiple at the same index in multiple rows.  I have functions that return the name of the piece and its initial position and one that returns the name of the square and the position where I want the piece to end up.  Here is my code.

```js
function move(piece, square) {
    piecePosition = findPiece(piece);
    squarePosition = findSquare(square);
    board[0][piecePosition[1]][piecePosition[2]] = '#';
    board[0][squarePosition[1]][squarePosition[2]] =  piece;
    console.log(board);
};    
move("we2", "e4");
```

Comment: Is the **board** variable a 1-D array with multiple 1-D arrays in it? If so, you only need 2 indexed like **board[rowIndex][columnIndex]**

Comment: what is the meaning of `'w'`? please add the missing function as well as the board.

Comment: The board is an array of 2 2d arrays.  The functions find piece and find sqaure return the values of their indexes within the 2d arrays that are in the array. They just iterate with for loops looking through the array until there is a match